# Regex: Everything except some pattern

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a string:

> foo bar
>   foo1 #9 0x103806f4 bar1
>   foo2 #10 0x0f6dd704 bar2
>   foo3 bar3

I have tried the following:

> ^((?!#[\d]{1,2} 0x[0-9a-f]{8}).)*$

which gets

> foo bar
>   foo3 bar3

and

> ^((?!#[\d]{1,2} 0x[0-9a-f]{8}).)*

which gets

> foo bar 
>   foo1
>   foo2
>   foo3 bar3

But what im trying to get is

> foo bar
>   foo1 bar1
>   foo2 bar2
>   foo3 bar3

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do replace instead of matching in-order to get the desired output.

```
\s*#\d{1,2} 0x[0-9a-f]{8}
```

Use the above regex and then replace the match with an empty string.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yV8tG2/4)

Answer (score 3):

If you're wanting the beginning and ending non-whitespace characters, using a Negative Lookahead is not going to do the job. You could match your expected output as follows:

```
^(\S+).*?(\S+)$
```

Then in your preferred language, you can combine the match results: [python](/questions/tagged/python) example ...

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''foo bar
foo1 #9 0x103806f4 bar1
foo2 #10 0x0f6dd704 bar2
foo3 bar3'''
...
>>> for m in re.finditer(r'(?m)^(\S+).*?(\S+)$', s):
...     print(" ".join(m.groups()))

foo bar
foo1 bar1
foo2 bar2
foo3 bar3
```

Instead of using regex, consider splitting the string and joining the indexes together.